# How to break the loop in the case of some error has been caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, while-loop, xml-validation

Q:

I want to **break** the loop if some exception has been caught in the event.

## The code :

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.Load(targetFileName);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.CloseInput = true;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += Handler;

settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(null,System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/importSchema/IntialSchema.xsd"));
settings.ValidationFlags =
     XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

using (StreamReader str_reader = new StreamReader(targetFileName))
{

    using (XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(str_reader, settings))
    {
        while (validatingReader.Read())
        {
            //I wanna to break this loop if there is some caught error .
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private static void Handler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception(
                 String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                     e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.LinePosition, e.Exception.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Common.ErrMappingForInformix.WriteLog(ee.Message);
            ScheduleForm sf = new ScheduleForm();
            sf.ShowStatus("Error,Invalid xml file", "error", "", 1);

        }

    }

}
```

---

# Edit 1 :

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.Load(targetFileName);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.CloseInput = true;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (senderValidation, ee) =>
{
    if (ee.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || ee.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    {
        try
        {
            this.validationFailed = true;
            throw new Exception(
                 String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                     ee.Exception.LineNumber, ee.Exception.LinePosition, ee.Exception.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Common.ErrMappingForInformix.WriteLog(ex.Message);
            this.ShowStatus("Error", "error", "", 1);
        }

    }
};

settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(null, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/importSchema/IntialSchema.xsd"));
settings.ValidationFlags =
     XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

using (StreamReader str_reader = new StreamReader(targetFileName))
{

    using (XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(str_reader, settings))
    {
        while (validatingReader.Read())
        {
            //Loop through the document
            if (validationFailed)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> It breaks the loop but it doesn't execute the event handler.

Comment: Seems counter-intuitive. If it's been caught, then the error is not relevant anymore. So I very much doubt that a way of doing this exists, short of writing your own Error class with a static member. But my gut tells me you want to check someone else's error.

Comment: XML validation errors are sent to the validation handler, he's asking how to get notification of that fact back in the main loop

Comment: No, he's asking if he can find out whether or not it is the case that an exception got caught.

Comment: No, he's not.  Because he used the term 'caught' you are assuming he's referring to exceptions.  This is not the case.  He's throwing an exception currently *if* an error is 'caught' (i.e. flagged).

Comment: Ah... Well, I guess I didn't read the post well, so I suppose it's my bad. Judging by the first sentence, he had me going all in the wrong direction (the post did literally mention caught exceptions). Goes to show why terminology is important. My coworker still doesn't understand why I make a point out of insisting there are no pointers in PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a flag to indicate there's an error in the `Handler` method, then detect that flag and use `break;` if it's set.

In this case, it might be better to use an inline anonymous delegate for the validation handler, so you don't need to add a new member variable to the class containing the methods.  (Adding a member variable isn't so bad if the class *only* deals with XML reading/validation)

Edit: anonymous inline delegate means you can add an event handler that doesn't have to be in a separate method, basically.  For example:

```
bool validationFailed = false; // outside of the handler
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Severity == XmlS....
    // set validationFailed = true; in here to signal failure
};

// then detect validationFailed being true to know if/when to break;
```

Comment: Excuse me .Could u clarify more about `inline anonymous delegate`?

Comment: @just_name: Edit your question, not this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply throw the exception in the Handler and break control flow when catching it. However, also avoid throwing too general exception types: better is to use a custom exception:

```
class XmlValidationFailedException : Exception {
   public XmlValidationFailedException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) {}

   // as per Kieren's comment, make sure this exception type is defined according to best practices
}


private static void Handler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    {
        string message = String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                     e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.LinePosition, e.Exception.Message)

        throw new XmlValidationFailedException(message);
    }
```

Then your loop can become something like:

```
try
{
   while (validatingReader.Read())
   {
       // do logic
   }
}
catch (XmlValidationException ex)
{
    // handle the error (log, show, ...) 
    return;
}
```

Comment: FYI The exception should be tagged with `Serializable`, have at least a few standard constructors and some more.  You can use the `exception` snippet in Visual Studio or look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx (section "Defining Exception Classes")

Comment: i have some code after the exception , and if the exception thrown .i want the exception handler is last thing to executed

Comment: and one more thing the `break;` can't be used in this block.

Comment: i do the following:
`using (StreamReader str_reader = new StreamReader(targetFileName))
                                {
                                    using (XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(str_reader, settings))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
 while (validatingReader.Read())
                                            {
                                            }
                                        }`

Comment: `catch (XmlValidationFailedException ex)
                                        {
                                            Common.ErrMappingForInformix.WriteLog(ex.Message);
                         
                                            validationFailed = true;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                if (validationFailed)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }`

Comment: `[Serializable()]
    public class XmlValidationFailedException : System.Exception
    {
        public XmlValidationFailedException() : base() { }
        public XmlValidationFailedException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public XmlValidationFailedException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

        protected XmlValidationFailedException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
            System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) { }
    }`

Comment: `private static void Handler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            {
                string message = String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                             e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.LinePosition, e.Exception.Message);

                throw new XmlValidationFailedException(message, e.Exception);
            }
        }`

Comment: @KierenJohnstone, you're right of course, though that was not really the point of the question. Edited my answer to refer to your comment anyway.

Comment: @just_name, there was an error in my original answer indeed, adjusted. But I don't intend to give complete working code, just a hint in the right direction.